# Twisted graph duplication

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology

I want to know if the following operation on graphs is already studied or considered somewhere, and if so what it is used for and what it's called.

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a directed graph. Define $d(G)$ to be the Graph with vertices $V \times \{0, 1\}$ and edges being comprised of

- $((v, 0), (u, 0))$ for $(u, v) \in E$,
- $((u, 1), (v, 1))$ for $(u, v) \in E$, and
- $((u, 0), (u, 1))$ for $u \in V$.

Comment: It may be helpful to consider the operation on adjacency matrices, which sends $A\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
A^T& I\\
0& A
\end{pmatrix}$. Maybe this has a standard linear algebra interpretation.